# Windows Azure Tools: Unable to start Development Storage. Port conflict with existing application

Tags: c#, azure

I am teaching Windows Azure, and i made terminal server where each student can login and use Azure (VS2010 + Sdk 1.8 )

When two or more students are starting the AZURE application i get this alert :

"Windows Azure Tools: Failed to initialize Windows Azure storage emulator. Unable to start Development Storage. Port conflict with existing application."

This is probably because everyone use the same port , no ?
Who can i solve this conflict? can i use different storage port for each student ?
Thanks,
Erez

Comment: [this will help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh472164.aspx)

Comment: @astaykov the link is not working (page does not exist)

Comment: Vegar, this question is exactly 1 year old. I cannot be responsible for when and how Microsoft shange their documentation and delete content. But anyway, the question is very very specific. If you describe your issue in a new question you might get help. I really can't remember what resource I pointed here one year ago.